# datatable.select() with gridview and datatable

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

Can you compare a gridview value with a datatable value in a datatable.select() statement? If this is possible, this seems like the way to set it up.  I need to work with the datatable rows that match the gridview rows.

Similar to this:

```
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvMaps.Rows

    For Each dtrow As DataRow In indt.Select(gvRow.DataItem("Policy") & "=" & dtrow("Policy") & " AND " & _
                                       "'" & gvRow.DataItem("LineCounty") & "'='" & dtrow("LineCounty") & "' AND " & _
                                             gvRow.DataItem("Section") & "=" & dtrow("Section"))

    'code handling only returned rows from datatable.select()

    Next
Next
```

Comment: you could use a DataView instead of `.Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do it that way, when you call Select on indt, the select query expects something of the form name=value, so i imagine this may work better (apologies if i mangled the quotes)

```
dim query As String = "Policy='" & gvRow.DataItem("Policy") & "' AND " & _
                      "LineCounty='" & gvRow.DataItem("LineCounty") & "' AND " & _
                      "Section=" & gvRow.DataItem("Section") 
For Each dtrow As DataRow In indt.Select(query)
```

This said, for a large dataset this will not be fast, and it may be better to store some of this information (the data in the DataTable) in a class with a method to fetch data by Policy,LineCounty,Section triplets using an underlying dictionary etc..

Comment: This wont be a large dataset, but I see your point.  I changed my statement to model what you wrote, and I get this error "Object variable or With block variable not set."  Is this talking about my gvRow object?

Comment: I would advise you to seperate the query as above from the line which actually calls indt.Select(...) this way you can inspect your query string in the debugger (and make sure that the line building the query is not at fault)... also maybe confirm that the DataTable does in fact contain all of the exactly named columns Policy,LineCounty,Section.. other than that I'm not familiar with that error.